# Switching 1 row with few columns into 1 column with few rows in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, t-sql

i've got 1 row with many columns:

col1|col2|col3|...

and i want to have 1 column with many rows, like that:

col1
col2
col3
..

Answer (score 1):

`UNPIVOT` if you're using version 2005+

http://www.tsqltutorials.com/unpivot.php

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server 2000 or lower...

How to rotate a table in SQL Server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175574

Comment: The link is for PIVOTing a table - the OP describes UNPIVOTing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT, col4 INT);
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (1,2,3,4);

SELECT col, value FROM Table1
UNPIVOT (value FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)) AS unpvt
```

Result:

```
col  value
col1 1
col2 2
col3 3
col4 4
```

If you don't want to know which value came from which column, only select `value`:

```
SELECT value FROM Table1
UNPIVOT (value FOR col IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)) AS unpvt
```